# c# .net 6.0 I can't leave cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am sending username and password by react for login process. If the username and password are correct, I want the user's browser to set the token as a cookie. but it doesn't throw.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Token>> Login( UserLogin userLogin)
        {
            User user = await context.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Email == userLogin.Email && x.Password == userLogin.Password);
            
            if(user != null)
            {
                TokenHandler tokenHandler = new TokenHandler(configuration);
                Token token = tokenHandler.CreateAccessToken(user);
                user.RefreshToken = token.RefreshToken;
                user.RefrestTokenEndDate = token.Expiration.AddMinutes(3);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();


                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8),
                    Path = "/login"
                };
                Response.Cookies.Append("RefreshToken", token.RefreshToken, cookieOptions);
                Response.Cookies.Append("AccessToken", token.AccessToken, cookieOptions);

                return Ok(token);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

> login adress: http://localhost:3000/login

The token and verification process works without any issues. There is a problem with the cookie part...

Comment: why are you only assigning the cookie to the `/login` path? that will restrict it.

Comment: @DanielA.White I tried other things besides login but none of them worked. I tried without giving path, it still didn't work. I tried hundreds of methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you used React to create a frontend app and .net 6 to create the server backend, so the port are different with each other. So you may set Cors policy in your .net 6 application.

Here's some of my assumption. Firstly, you may try this cookieOption and have a test, learn about [SameSiteMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-core-support-for-the-samesite-attribute):

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8),
    //Path = "localhost",
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = true
};
```

I did a test in my side with an ajax request like this

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:7016/",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
});
```

And my cors policy:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "my",
       policy =>
       {
 policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8848").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I solved the problem myself. I was running my react project as 'http'. When I run it as 'https' the problem is gone. An ssl certificate is required.